# String[]-Array in ListBox

Tags: c#, arrays, string, listbox

I'm rather new to programing and especially to c#.
I want to import a Txt-File to a listBox.
I using following code, but all I get to see in the listBox are several lines with "String[]-Array" and not the real line from the Text-File.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox2.Text = op.FileName;
    }

    List<string[]> lines = File.ReadLines(textBox2.Text)
                           .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
                           .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                           .ToList();
    listBox1.DataSource = lines;

}
```

Can you help me out and maybe give me a small hint what a did wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: take a look at displaymember and value member

Comment: thank you, I will have a closer look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the text file supplied, this is what you'll require.  Just tested it with your text file and works, full code is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = op.FileName;
        }

        List<string[]> lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text)
                .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                .ToList();

        foreach (String[] item in lines)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item[0] + " " + item[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this only gives me the line in the brackets [0]. How can I loop thru all lines?

Comment: Check my edit and let me know if this works, I'm away from my laptop at the moment so can double check this in the morning if you have an issues

Comment: It still only puts the first row of the textfile in the listbox but seperates it in different rows in the listbox.

Comment: do you have the text file that you're using so I can check it against the code?  thanks

Comment: You can download the test-textfile here:

https://mega.nz/#!kahiiawZ!U823DrKRucUNPoKUJWFsJP1TK1bP8YqTywtHEE_4tYk

Comment: cheers, what information are you wanting to display in the listbox?  first name, surname, firstname and surname together?

Comment: Name and Surname in one line. I know that they are split up in two lines because of the delimiter. My problem is, that only the name and surname from the first line are imported.

Comment: I saw that you changed the code again. Now it works as it should. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah, I made an update, at the moment it'll just show the First name on each line, I've just updated it again now, so it'll show the First Name (item[0]) and Surname (item[1]) with a space between them.  If you need anything else, just ask.  Hopefully that's enough to get you going though, feel free to upvote and mark this as the answer if you're satisfied with this

Answer (score 0):

The final `Select(line => line.Split(',')` returns an *array*; you, probably, want either *array's item*

```
...
List<string[]> lines = File
  .ReadLines(textBox2.Text)
  .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
  .Select(line => line.Split(',')[index]) //TODO: put the right index here
  .ToList();
...
```

or the entire line (drop `Split`)

```
... 
 List<string[]> lines = File
  .ReadLines(textBox2.Text)
  .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
  .ToList();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what data is in your text file, I can give you only some general info:

The listbox typically consumes a source like `List<itemObject>`.
The `itemObject` should contain at least a *value* field or property (e.g. "id") that will identify the option in the listbox, and a *text* field that contains the text shown to the user (e.g. "name").

When the user clicks on a *text*, you probably want to handle a clicked event on the listbox and get the corresponding *value* to do something with it.

So does your textfile relate to this concept of *value* and *text* and can you create a list of objects of it? When it does, you can go two routes:

**Route 1:**
`listBox1.DataSource = listObject;`

When you do WinForms, set DisplayMember and ValueMember also when you set DataSource.

```
listBox1.DataSource = listObject;
listBox1.DisplayMember= "SomeDescriptionField";
listBox1.ValueMember = "AnIdField";
```

In Asp.net you would do something like

```
listBox1.DataSource = listObject;
listBox1.DataTextField = "SomeDescriptionField";
listBox1.DataValueField = "AnIdField";
listBox1.DataBind();
```

If you don't, the listBox will show the list.ToString(), and that is probably what happened.

**Route 2:**
`listBox1.Items.AddRange(listObject.ToArray());`

(or in an iteration you can do `listBox1.Items.Add(...)`)

Comment: For now, I do not want anything to happen if a user clicks on the listbox. All I want to do is to have the listbox filled with the content of a textfile. The content is a normal list of names. 
I tried both routes but all I get is the same as before. 
Here is a pic of how the ListBox looks like after the textfile is imported.

https://picload.org/view/rpwdriwl/string-array.jpg.html

Comment: Can you add an example of the text file content?